# Entity Framework with MySQL not working

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying Entity Framework with MySQL for first time. I am using the code from `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html`for sample coding. I am using the code as it is(no change)
. My App.config file is like this -

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=act_saga;uid=root;password=ABcdEf32!"/>
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
<codeConfiguration Type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
     type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
</configuration>
```

I am using MySQL Server 5.7, Entity Framework 6.1.3, MySQL.Data 6.10.4, MySQL.Data.Entity 6.10.4 and MySQL Connector/Net 6.10.4 .

While debugging, I found that for the line

```
using (Parking contextDB = new Parking(connection, false))
```

is throwing the exception

```
"Inheritance security rules violated by type: 
'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Derived types must either match the 
security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible. The stack 
trace is as follows -
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, 
IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, 
IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule 
decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType 
attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, 
Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo element, Type type, Boolean inherit)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](MemberInfo element, Boolean inherit)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationFinder.TryFindConfigurationType(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint, IEnumerable`1 typesToSearch)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean contextOwnsConnection)
at MySQLWithEF.Parking..ctor(DbConnection existingConnection, Boolean contextOwnsConnection) in C:\Users\vsinghthakur\Desktop\Knowledge\MySQLWithEF\MySQLWithEF\Parking.cs:line 26
at MySQLWithEF.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\vsinghthakur\Desktop\Knowledge\MySQLWithEF\MySQLWithEF\Program.cs:line 21
```

I tried a lot by changing the config, shifting the position of connection string, uninstalling and reinstalling packages, but nothing worked.

What am I missing ? It is a sample code from MySQL site.

Comment: With such a generic exception, I would expect that there are nested exceptions. Can you include those too please?

Comment: Now I am getting the exception - "Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
" . There is no inner exception.

Comment: Now , I am getting the exception - {"Procedure or function '`Car_Insert`' cannot be found in database '`pct_saga`'."} System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}
.

Comment: That looks like a different question at this point. You will get better help if you post the new one, and eliminate everything that doesn't have to do with your new problem.